# Difference between weak * convergence and SOT convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis

If one regards a sequence of functionals as members of a space of operators I think we have that these notions coincide, am I right?

$\ell_{n}$ conv. weak * in $X^{'}$ to $\ell$ if $lim_{n} x(\ell_{n})=x( \ell )$ for all $x \in X$

while $\ell_{n}$ converge to $\ell$ in SOT if it converges pointwise.

Comment: On what are those functionals defined? Banach space?

Comment: @wroobell yes they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $X,Y$ are real Banach spaces, $X^*,Y^*$ spaces of all continous functionals on $X,Y$ respectively. Because of linearity of topologies we regard we will only consider convergence to zero functional. Lets examine these two notions:

1. *-weak convergence -- Let $(x^*_n)$ be a sequence of functionals. We say, that $(x^*_n)$ converges *-weakly to zero- functional if for any $ x \in X$ we have $\lim_n <x_n^*,x> = 0$.
   Putting it in quatifiers:
   $$ \forall x \forall \varepsilon >0 \exists N \forall n > N  \; |< x^*_n , x > | < \varepsilon $$
2. Strong operator convergence -- Let $(T_n)$ be a sequence of operators from $\mathcal B (X,Y)$. We say that $(T_n)$ converges in a strong operator sense to zero operator, if for all $x \in X$ we have $\lim_n T_n(x) = 0_Y$.

In your case $Y = \mathbb R$, so You are right, these notions coincide.

Comment: Ok, i misread something. What is SOT?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_topologies

Comment: Ok, i am not english-native,  so I didnt know this abbreviation. Maybe I just delete my answer because it is irrelevant?

Comment: maybe change it to right definitions if you know the answer.

Comment: Do You only know about convergence of sequences or also about topologies?

Comment: You mean in general? If I know toplogy?

Comment: About how to define a weak, *-weak topologies etc. by families of seminorms.

Comment: Cant say I do, all I know that its the weakest topology making certian functions continous. I never worked with seminorms. In the case of SOT its the coarsetst making $T$ ->$Tx$ continuous for all $x$

Comment: Yes, this is almost the same. But I answered using sequences. Sorry for previous mess.

Comment: Have any questions?

Comment: no, this looks like it makes sense. But why do you say almost?

Comment: Well, you are right and this almost was unnesecary. But with this definition we dont know anything about that topology. By constructing it with seminorms we know that it is locally convex and know its prebasis.